# How to respond to questions "Have you got it" in checking for understanding context

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm studying English and I am confused how to respond "Have you got it?" in checking for understanding context. Is it "Yes, we got it?" or "Yes, we've got it?"

Comment: "Have you got it?" is pretty informal and slangy, so this US English speaker would feel fine responding with the informal, "Yes, we got it" or just "We got it" or even just "Got it."

Comment: Generally, either *Yes, we got it* or *Yes, we've got it* are always interchangeable. To be fussy, *we got it* replies to *Did you get it* but really, there's no difference. 

Sometimes, people will take offence if you use *Have you got/did you get it?* for the reason that it sounds like *Do you understand*

For that reason I aim always to use *Does that make sense* which is testing my understanding, not theirs.

Answer (score 1):

You must be studying British English, because I can't actually imagine someone asking me "Have you got it?" in American English.

I would guess that in British English, where present perfect is much more common and *got* is the proper past participle of *get*, this doesn't sound as "slangy" as it does in American English.

So if you are treating this as proper English, then you should pretty much always just answer the question in the *same* tense in which it was asked:

> Have you got it?
> Yes, **we've** got it.

In American English, this question is more likely to be asked in the present tense, when being proper:

> Do you get it?
> Yes, we get it.

Amusingly, we still seem to take some of our slang from the forms that are proper in BrE. This is something like a meme:

> Got it?
> Got it!
> Good!

Answer (score 0):

As stangdon said, this is fairly slangy. However, I personally would not say "Yes, we've got it." If you break apart the contraction, you have:

> Yes, we have got it.

This implies that you got it, in the past. I would usually either say:

> Yes, we got it.

or

> Yes, we have it.

Note that (as far as I can tell) "Yes, we've got it" is grammatically correct, and could have its uses. "Yes, we've gotten it" may be the correct way to say it.

Comment: Why do you think that Present Perfect implies the past? And **gotten** is simply Am.E.